# Create new Excel rows based on column data

Tags: excel

Good afternoon all,

I have an issue where I have users who have multiple bank account details. I need to try and create a new row for each employee who has more than one bank account, with the second bank account being allocated a new row.

```
Employee Number     User ID         BSB             Account number
10000591            WOODSP0         306089,116879   343509,041145273
10000592            THOMSOS0        037125          317166
```

[image: Screenshot 1]

I need it to look something like this:

```
Employee Number     User ID     BSB     Account number
10000591            WOODSP0     306089  343509
10000591            WOODSP0     116879  041145273
10000592            THOMSOS0    037125  317166
```

[image: Screenshot 2]

Any thoughts? Your input is greatly appreciated!

Screenshots are here to demonstrate:

Comment: Could you please format your examples (preferably replacing tabs with spaces) and explain what do the commas mean and why is the zero gone?

Comment: And, anyway, I’m afraid Excel can’t do what you are asking for. You’ll either have to wright a macro in VBA or export your data, process it using some other tool, and import back.

Comment: This can be done fairly quickly with VBA.  It involves using `Split` on the two columns of interest and processing the results, adding rows and copying the stuff that doesn't change.  If this is the route you want to go, you will need to take a stab at it and let us know what does not work.  Very few people will write this from scratch for you.

Comment: is VBA the only option? Just a bit worried because I have not used VBA before :/

Answer (score 1):

Right click on the tab and choose "View Code"

Paste this code in:

```
Sub SplitOnAccount()
Dim X As Long, Y As Long, EmpNo As String, UserID As String, BSB As Variant, AccNo As Variant
Range("F1:I1") = Application.Transpose(Application.Transpose(Array(Range("A1:D1"))))
For X = 2 To Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    EmpNo = Range("A" & X).Text
    UserID = Range("B" & X).Text
    BSB = Split(Range("C" & X).Text, ",")
    AccNo = Split(Range("D" & X).Text, ",")
    For Y = LBound(AccNo) To UBound(AccNo)
        Range("F" & Range("F" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Offset(1, 0).Formula = EmpNo
        Range("G" & Range("G" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Offset(1, 0).Formula = UserID
        Range("H" & Range("H" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Offset(1, 0).Formula = BSB(Y)
        Range("I" & Range("I" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Offset(1, 0).Formula = AccNo(Y)
    Next
Next
End Sub
```

Close the window to go back to excel

Press ALT-F8

Choose SplitOnAccount and click run.

Note, this is going to populate the split data to rows F to I, make sure there is nothing in there. If there is post back and we can change it.

Also format columns F - I as text before you run it or Excel will strip leading zeros off as it will interpret it as a number.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another sub that appears to perform what you are looking for.

```
Sub stack_accounts()
    Dim rw As Long, b As Long
    Dim vVALs As Variant, vBSBs As Variant, vACTs As Variant

    With ActiveSheet   '<-define this worksheet properly!
        For rw = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row To 2 Step -1
            vVALs = .Cells(rw, 1).Resize(1, 4).Value
            vBSBs = Split(vVALs(1, 3), Chr(44))
            vACTs = Split(vVALs(1, 4), Chr(44))
            If UBound(vBSBs) = UBound(vBSBs) Then
                For b = UBound(vBSBs) To LBound(vBSBs) Step -1
                    If b > LBound(vBSBs) Then _
                        .Rows(rw + 1).Insert
                    .Cells(rw - (b > LBound(vBSBs)), 1).Resize(1, 4) = vVALs
                    .Cells(rw - (b > LBound(vBSBs)), 3).Resize(1, 2).NumberFormat = "@"
                    .Cells(rw - (b > LBound(vBSBs)), 3) = CStr(vBSBs(b))
                    .Cells(rw - (b > LBound(vBSBs)), 4) = CStr(vACTs(b))
                Next b
            End If
        Next rw
    End With
End Sub
```

I was originally only going to process the rows that had comma delimited values in columns C and D but I thought that processing all of them would allow the macro to set the *Text* number format and get rid of the *Number as text* error warnings and keep the leading zero in *041145273*.

[image: Split accounts and add new row(s)]

Answer (score 1):

You Can definitely use Power Query to transform the data to generate new rows using split column option.

Check [this article](https://www.techrepublic.com/article/a-super-easy-way-to-generate-new-records-from-multi-value-columns-using-excels-power-query/) it explains the process in detail.

1. Load Data in Power Query section of excel.
2. Create an Index (Not required step)
3. Use Split column function with advance options and split them into new rows.
4. Save this result into new table for your use.

I did it myself and it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

A formula solution:

[image: Image shown here.]

Delimiter: Can be a real delimiter or an absolute reference to a cell containing only the delimiter.

HelperCol: I have to use a helper column to make it work. You need to give the column letter.

StartCol: The column letter of the first column containing data.

SplitCol: The column letter of the column to be splitted.

Formula1: Used to generate the formula for the first column not to be splitted. You can fill this formula down and then fill to right.

Formula2: Used to generate the formula for the column to be splitted(only support split one column).

Formula3: Used to generate the formula for the Helper column.
 (If the title of the column to be splitted contains the delimiter, you must change the first value of the helper column to 1 manually.)

```
Formula1:=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE("=LOOKUP(ROW(1:1),$J:$J,A:A)&""""","$J:$J","$"&B2&":$"&B2),"A:A",B3&":"&B3)

Formula2:=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE("=MID($M$1&LOOKUP(ROW(A1),$J:$J,F:F)&$M$1,FIND(""艹"",SUBSTITUTE($M$1&LOOKUP(ROW(A1),$J:$J,F:F)&$M$1,$M$1,"&"""艹"",ROW(A2)-LOOKUP(ROW(A1),$J:$J)))+1,FIND(""艹"",SUBSTITUTE($M$1&LOOKUP(ROW(A1),$J:$J,F:F)&$M$1,$M$1,""艹"",ROW(A2)-LOOKUP(ROW(A1),$J:$J)+1))-FIND(""艹"",SUBSTITUTE($M$1&LOOKUP(ROW(A1),$J:$J,F:F)&$M$1,$M$1,""艹"",ROW(A2)-LOOKUP(ROW(A1),$J:$J)))-1)&""""","$M$1",IF(ISERROR(INDIRECT(B1)),""""&B1&"""",B1)),"$J:$J","$"&B2&":$"&B2),"F:F",B4&":"&B4)

Formula3:=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE("=SUM(E1,LEN(B1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(B1,$H$1,"""")))+1","B1",B4&1),"$H$1",IF(ISERROR(INDIRECT(B1)),""""&B1&"""",B1)),"E1",B2&1)
```

Helper must filled one row more than the data.

How to use:

1. Copy the formula generated by the above three formula.
2. Use Paste Special only paste the value.
3. Make the formula into effect.
4. Fill the formula.

Bug:

Numbers will be converted to Text. Of course you can remove the &"" at the end of the formula, but blank cells will be filled with 0.

ps. This method may by very hard to comprehend. But once you master it, it can be very useful to solve relative problems.